# CorePlot error by install: Property attributes error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, automatic-ref-counting

After installing `CorePlot` I get the following errors:

`Property attributes 'assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive`

[image: Screenshot]

What does that mean?

Thank you!

Comment: OK, solved ... seems like it has something to do with `ARC` and `non-ARC` project handling. Removing `__weak` at the `.h-Files` helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you're trying to use the 0.9 snapshot or a version that isn't the current one in the repository.  The headers were not compatible with an ARC-enabled project until about a month or so ago.

Pull the latest version of the framework from the Mercurial repository to fix this.  There are a few more subtle things that needed to be modified in the headers to make this ARC-compatible than just pulling out the `__weak` symbols. The latest version in the repository is fully tested and compatible with a ARC-enabled applications targeting iOS 4.0, 5.0, Snow Leopard, and Lion.

Comment: What's the current build number? I got `core-plot_0.9` from `GoogleCode`. Do you maybe have a download link? I can't find a newer one ... Thanks!

Comment: @Darwin - 0.9 is just a snapshot of the Mercurial repository as of a few months ago. You'll want to stay on top of the latest changes in the framework by pulling down the current code in the repository following these instructions: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingMercurial The repository itself is located here: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout